# How can I get my variables out of a function so that I can store them in a session?

Tags: javascript, html

I and my project group have been trying to create a web application that uses a geocoding plugin to transform user input into coordinates to use in a Leaflet map. I want to store the longitude and the latitude of the address in the current session and I currently do so using sessionStorage.setItem(). However, when I'm trying to access them from the referred page, I see that they are null using sessionStorage.getItem(). I know where the issue is but do not know how to solve it.

```
        // call Geocoding API using a GET request- https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api/
        fetch(geocodingUrl).then(result => result.json()) //fetch result in a json file
                .then(featureCollection => {
                    //Check if json is empty
                    if (featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
                        alert("The address is not found");
                        return;
                    }

                    //The following 2 commands get the full address from the json file fetched by the API.
                    const foundAddress = featureCollection.features[0];
                    document.getElementById("City Address").value = foundAddress.properties.name || '';

                    //Used for testing
                    console.log(foundAddress);
                    console.log(foundAddress.properties.lat + " at " + foundAddress.properties.lon);

                    var lon = foundAddress.properties.lon;
                    var lat = foundAddress.properties.lat;

                    //Save Coords of user for use in the next session (SearchResults.html)
                    sessionStorage.setItem("UserLon", lon);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("UserLat", lat);

    });
```

foundAddress is part of a JSON file that includes the information I need and its properties such as name(full address), longitude, latitude etc.

I tried playing with the variables and their scopes in any way I could but to no avail. When I try doing console.log outside the }); clause, the items are null and are consequently not stored in the session. Any ideas on how I can fix that issue and manage to store the coordinates in the session successfully?

Thank you in advance for you responses!

Edit:  I forgot to add that lon and lat do indeed take their corresponding values. It is just that they don't get saved in the session using sessionStorage.setItem().

Additional Edit:

Here is the whole (and only) method of the main page in case that might provide some additional needed information.

```
function direct() {
        //For additional domains, add exceptions to API settings at https://myprojects.geoapify.com/api/pI8Dn2CPBgIsDpGfrasA/keys.
        const APIkey = "myAPIkey";
        var address = document.getElementById("CityAddress").value;

        sessionStorage.setItem("city", address);
        sessionStorage.setItem("type", document.getElementById("BuildingType").value);

        //
        const geocodingUrl = `https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?text=${encodeURIComponent(address)}&apiKey=${APIkey}&filter=countrycode:nl`;

        // call Geocoding API using a GET request- https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api/
        fetch(geocodingUrl).then(result => result.json()) //fetch result in a json file
                .then(featureCollection => {
                    //Check if json is empty
                    if (featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
                        alert("The address is not found");
                        return;
                    }

                    //The following 2 commands get the full address from the json file fetched by the API.
                    const foundAddress = featureCollection.features[0];
                    document.getElementById("CityAddress").value = foundAddress.properties.name || '';

                    //Used for testing
                    console.log(foundAddress);
                    console.log(foundAddress.properties.lat + " at " + foundAddress.properties.lon);

                    var lon = foundAddress.properties.lon;
                    var lat = foundAddress.properties.lat;

                    //Save Coords of user for use in the next session (SearchResults.html)
                    sessionStorage.setItem("UserLon", lon);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("UserLat", lat);

    });
    }
```

The 1st 2 sessionStorage.setItem() commands work just fine and are being stored for use in the website which I refer to by:

```
        <button onclick="direct();location.href='SearchResults.html';" type="button" style="width: 125px; height: 38px">
         Search</button>
```

By issuing console.log()'s on both this page and the one I refer to, the first 2 sessionStorage.setItem()'s work as intended. I tried getting "UserLon" & "UserLat" the same way I did the previous ones an got null values for those stored id's.

Final Edit:
I found the answer to my problem. The problem was that there was no time to fetch the data from the API in time and that is why I was getting null values within the function. I fixed that by making a timeout to wait for the data to be fetched and then be referred to the following page.

```
        setTimeout(() => {
            location.href="SearchResults.html";
        }, 1500);
```

I determined that 1500 ms is the safest boundary to get the results within time.

Comment: its seems to me that it's two different pages, opened using file://, in that case it wont work, localeStorage is not shared between pages, you will need to host your pages on a server, and access them using the same domain (ex: localhost )

Comment: It is not working cause `id` value does not contain any whitespace. In your case - 
change `document.getElementById("City Address")` to `document.getElementById("CityAddress")`

Comment: @Lk77 Thank you for your answer, I use Apache Tomcat to host my pages, I use sessionStorage.getItem for some other variables in this js class and it works.

Comment: @ShreyBhangale id can contain whitespace, it works fine, it's not really a good idea tho

Comment: Actually that was the same thing on my mind but When I crossed check, I found that I was wrong to begin with! 
See this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @ShreyBhangale Hello and thank you for taking the time to respond, unfortunately, that is not the issue, the address that I get from the id does work. I forgot to add that lon and lat do indeed take their corresponding values. It is just that they don't get saved in the session using sessionStorage.setItem().

Comment: Are you sure you're in the same [session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)? It must be the same origin in the same tab.

Comment: @jsejcksn Hey! I am indeed in the same session as I use sessionStorage.setItem() for 2 other values I want to store and am able to access them with no issues on the page I refer to.

Comment: @SteliosKs Are you sure they're being set? Perhaps your response has no features, so it `return`s early per your logic.

Comment: @jsejcksn I added a few additional edits that hopefully answer your question. But to put it simply, the 1st 2 sessionStorage.setItem()'s work as intended while the last 2 ones that have longitude and latitude don't.